# Lookup magnifier glass moves to the left

Tags: visualforce

When I just have the composition and define included on the page, the lookup magnifier glass moves to the left (ahead of the lookup text box), when I remove these tags, it restores to it's normal position. Has anyone seen this before? if so, how do I get the magnifier glass to get back to the normal position (right of lookup box). Code below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false">

 <apex:composition template="Template">
     <apex:define name="body" >

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="mainDetail">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Parent1 Account" />
                    <apex:outputPanel>
                     <apex:inputfield value="{!account.parentid}"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:define> 
</apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```